# How to go about identifying nodes in an HTML tree that are semantically related but not structurally

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am facing the following problem, as it seems the HTML on Wiktionary is laid out in a way where the sections for the individual languages are not actually nodes dominating the entries in the corresponding section. I would like to grab data from the section for some specific language only, say English. The data I might be interested in is for example the span "IPA" : `<span class="IPA" lang="">/dɒɡ/</span>`, however this span occurs several times:

`[<span class="IPA" lang="">/dɒɡ/</span>, <span class="IPA" lang="">/dɔɡ/</span>, <span class="IPA" lang="">/dɑɡ/</span>, <span class="IPA" lang="">-ɒɡ</span>, <span class="IPA" lang="">/ˈdɔɡ/</span>, <span class="IPA" lang="">/ˈdɔ.ɡi/</span>, <span class="IPA" lang="">[doɡ]</span>]`

But only on of the items belongs to the section for English. The others belong to among others Portuguese and Volapük. The span marking the English section (`<span class="mw-headline" id="English">English</span>`) however is not a predecessor node of the IPA-span node, therefore it is not apparent how to go about collecting the right data based on an HTML parse, as I was trying so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from sys import argv

def find_IPA(
    r = requests.get('https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/'+word)
    content = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.decode('utf-8','ignore'),'lxml')
    print (soup.findAll('span', {'class' : "IPA"}))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        find_IPA(argv[1])
    except Exception as e:
        print(format(e))
```

So, is there a better way to deal with a situation in an HTML file like this where semantic relatedness is disjoint from structural relatedness?

(The example bits came from this page> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no structure in the HTML and the sections are flat and lack DOM hierarchy, one option would be to select the 'English' header and then iterate over all of the next sibling elements until you encounter another `h2` element containing a `.mw-headline` header.

In doing so, you are essentially selecting all of the sibling elements within the 'English' section.

From there, you can select all the desired `.IPA` elements.

```
english_header = soup.find('span', {'id': 'English', 'class': 'mw-headline'})

if english_header:
    next_sibling = english_header.parent.find_next_sibling()

    while next_sibling and not (next_sibling.name == 'h2' and next_sibling.select('.mw-headline')):
        for element in next_sibling.select('.IPA'):
            print(element)

        next_sibling = next_sibling.find_next_sibling()
```